# Method not returning same when called on the same object

Tags: java, methods, printing, linked-list, traversal

Title is confusing, but I had no idea how to describe it otherwise.  I'm building a Linked List of Cars objects, and all is well, I'm printing the list by calling my getElement method.  If it do it on let's say corvette, so `System.out.print(corvette.getElement);`, it just displays `corvette` like I want it to.  But if I do the same with my `traverse` method when `corvette` is in the list, it spits out `linklist.Cars@5f531aca`.   Code below.

```
public class LinkList <E>
{
private Cars<E> head;
private Cars<E> tail;
private static int length;    

public int getLength()
{
    return length;
}

public LinkList()
{
    tail = new Cars();
    head = new Cars(null, tail);
    length = 0;
}

public void traverse()
{
    Cars<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();

    while(cursor != tail)
    {
        System.out.println(cursor.getElement());
        cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
    }
}

public Cars<E> find(int pos)
{
    if(pos < 0 || pos >= this.length)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Cars<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();

    for(int index = 0; index < pos; ++index)
    {
        cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
    }

    return cursor;
}

public Cars<E> find(E element)
{
    Cars<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();

    while(cursor != tail)
    {
        if(!cursor.getElement().equals(element))
            cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
        else return cursor;
    }

    return null;
}

public void addAtHead(E element)
{
    Cars<E> newNode = new Cars<>(element, null);

    newNode.setSuccessor(head.getSuccessor());

    head.setSuccessor(newNode);

    ++length;
}

public void insert(E element, int pos)
{
    if(pos < 0 || pos > this.length)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        addAtHead(element);
    }
    else if(pos == length)
    {
        addAtTail(element);
    }
    else
    {
        Cars<E> newNode = new Cars<>(element, null);

        Cars<E> prevNode = find(pos - 1);

        newNode.setSuccessor(prevNode.getSuccessor());
        prevNode.setSuccessor(newNode);
        ++length;
    }
}

public void addAtTail(E element)
{
    Cars<E> newNode = new Cars<>(element, null);

    if(length > 0)
    {
        Cars<E> lastNode = find(this.length - 1);

        newNode.setSuccessor(lastNode.getSuccessor());
        lastNode.setSuccessor(newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        newNode.setSuccessor(head.getSuccessor());
        head.setSuccessor(newNode);
    }

    ++length;
}

public E delete(int pos)
{
    if(pos < 0 || pos >= this.length)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Cars<E> prevNode;
    if(pos == 0)
    {
        prevNode = head;
    }
    else
    {
        prevNode = find(pos - 1);
    }

    Cars<E> poorUnfortunateSoul = prevNode.getSuccessor();
    prevNode.setSuccessor(poorUnfortunateSoul.getSuccessor());
    poorUnfortunateSoul.setSuccessor(null);
    --length;

    return poorUnfortunateSoul.getElement();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Cars corvette = new Cars("corvette", null);
    Cars pinto = new Cars("pinto", null);
    Cars mustang = new Cars("mustang", null);
    Cars bmw = new Cars("bmw", null);
    Cars elio = new Cars("elio", null);
    LinkList list = new LinkList();

    list.addAtTail(corvette);
    list.addAtTail(pinto);
    list.addAtTail(mustang);
    list.addAtTail(bmw);
    list.addAtTail(elio);

    System.out.println(corvette.getElement());
    list.traverse();
```

the next is my Cars class.

```
public class Cars <E>
{
private E element;
private Cars successor;

public Cars()
{
    this.element = null;
    this.successor = null;
}

public Cars(E element, Cars<E> node)
{
    this.element = element;
    this.successor = node;
}

public E getElement()
{
    return this.element;
}

public void setElement(E element)
{
    this.element = element;
}

public Cars<E> getSuccessor()
{
    return this.successor;
}

public void setSuccessor(Cars successor)
{
    this.successor = successor;
}
}
```

Essentially the test method outputs:

```
corvette
linklist.Cars@5f531aca
linklist.Cars@4903f4aa
linklist.Cars@22b3ea59
linklist.Cars@51de8adb
linklist.Cars@696e59da
```

And I have no idea why, when they're both just printing the `getElement` method.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  I understand this is a stupid way to do things, but it is what it is (assignment).  What I really want to know is is why `corvette.getElement()` and `cursor.getElement` in the `traverse` method, provide different things, when they (from what I know) should be performing the exact same action.

Comment: Override `toString()` in your method to help debugging.

Comment: I have no idea why you're implementing a LinkedList manually instead of using a `java.util.LinkedList`, especially since your implementation is really, really poor. This must be a homework assignment.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, irritating I know, but the both classes are already written, and I can only manipulate the test method, so I'm just trying to make the stupid thing work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void addAtTail(E element)
```

This is supposed to take an `E`. In your case a String like `"corvette"`.

But you call the method with an `Cars<E>`.

```
   Cars corvette = new Cars("corvette", null);

   list.addAtTail(corvette);
```

As a result, your list elements are wrapped twice.

```
  Cars<E> newNode = new Cars<>(element, null);
```

Don't you get some type warnings?

You should be making use of your generic types:

```
 Cars<String> corvette = new Cars("corvette", null);
```

Then the compiler would detect the type mismatch and refuse to compile this code.

Comment: Not at all, Netbeans is totally happy with everything as it stands.  My understanding of Generics is shoddy at best, but it runs fine.

Comment: There must be a warning about `Cars` being generic and you not giving the type.

Comment: There really really isn't.  The problem is this is, obviously, an assignment.  Everything is prewritten and I'm simply supposed to manipulate the test method to build a list using the methods and constructors provided.  I fully recognize there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies in the fact that your `addAtTail` method accepts an `E` as a parameter, not a `Car` like you are providing. You should just call `addAtTail("corvette")`. This problem would be avoided if you actually made use of the generic class - that's what it's there for. Instead of `LinkList list = new LinkList();`, use `LinkList<String> list = new LinkList<String>();` (since you are putting strings in the list in this case), and similarly your `Cars` should be `Cars<String>`. That will keep you from accidentally adding the wrong type to the list, as is happening in this case.

EDIT: Also, your code seems to be confusing what exactly is a car and what is an element of the list. Your `Cars` class does not actually seem to represent a car. There is no need for a car object to know which car comes after it in the list. You should probably rename the `Cars` class something like `ListNode`, because each instance of that represents one node of the list. This node is not itself be a car, but it should contain a car - that is what the element field is for. The `Cars` class would then have just information about the car. Then you would have something such as:

```
LinkList<Car> list = new LinkList<Car>;
list.addAtTail(new Car("corvette"));
```

The `addAtTail` method would then create a `ListNode<Car>` object containing the car you just created, and add it to the list.

Comment: I get that, but it's an assignment, so I have to do it in this bizarre way.  What I'm curious about is why `corvette.getElement()` and `cursor.getElement` in the `traverse` method, provide different things, when they (from what I know) should be performing the exact same action.

Comment: The reason that they are returning different things is because your list does not contain `String`s, it contains `Cars`. When you type `list.addAtTail(corvette)`, it does not add the corvette object to the list. It creates a new `Cars`, called `newNode`, which contains `corvette` in its `element` field. Thus when you call `traverse`, it does not call `corvette`'s `getElement` method; instead it calls `newNode`'s `getElement` method. That is why it does not return the same result.